# How to check if the key exists in a deeply nested Map in Elixir

Tags: dictionary, elixir

I have a map object I need to check if it contain a given key. I tried like below but it always return false. Also how to pull value on inside map replyMessage,

```
map=%{
  Envelope: %{
    Body: %{
      replyMessage: %{
        cc: %{
          "amount" => "100.00",
          "reasonCode" => "100",
        },
        decision: "ACCEPT",
        invalidField: nil,
        purchaseTotals: %{"currency" => "CAD"},
        reasonCode: "100",

      }
    }
  }
}
Map.has_key?(map,  %{Envelope: %{Body: %{replyMessage: replyMessage}}})= false
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two possibilities: [`Kernel.match?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#match?/2) to check whether the key exists *and*/*or* [`Kernel.get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2) to deeply retrieve the value.

```rb
iex|1 ▶ match?(%{Envelope: %{Body: %{replyMessage: _}}}, map)      
#⇒ true

iex|2 ▶ get_in(map, [:Envelope, :Body, :replyMessage])
#⇒ %{
#   cc: %{"amount" => "100.00", "reasonCode" => "100"},
#   decision: "ACCEPT",
#   invalidField: nil,
#   purchaseTotals: %{"currency" => "CAD"},
#   reasonCode: "100"
# }
```

Beware of `Kernel.get_in/2` would return `nil` if the key exists, but has `nil` value, as well as if the key does not exist.

---

[`Map.has_key?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html?#has_key?/2) is not recursive by any mean, it works with the keys of the map, passed as an argument; that said, the first level only.

---

**Sidenote:** one might easily build a recursive solution themselves, based on `Map.has_key/2`

```rb
defmodule Deep do
  @spec has_key?(map :: map(), keys :: [atom()]) :: boolean()
  def has_key?(map, _) when not is_map(map), do: false
  def has_key?(map, [key]), do: Map.has_key?(map, key)
  def has_key?(map, [key|tail]),
    do: Map.has_key?(map, key) and has_key?(map[key], tail)
end

Deep.has_key?(map, [:Envelope, :Body, :replyMessage])
#⇒ true
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was using get_in() like below. But I think match? is more useful for me.  case _value=get_in(map, [:Envelope, :Body, :replyMessage])   do
      nil -> map
      value -> value
    end

Comment: How do I subscribe to your answers @aleksei-matiushkin?

Comment: @PeacefulJames I doubt it’s possible here on SO, but still thanks, I appreciate it. I have a blog, elixir RSS is here: https://rocket-science.ru/elixir-feed.xml

Comment: seems like  `Kernel.match?/2` does not work with string keys, it only works for atom keys

Comment: @PramodJangam it works with string keys like so 
match?(%{"Envelope" => %{"Body" => _}}, map)